# Plotting JSON from dict() to pie charts and bar graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have some JSON files written from `dict()` that I want to make a few plots from. So far I tried opening the JSON files as dataframes and plotting those, but it requires me to enable `subplots=True` giving me separate plots for each value. Not specifying this renders an error. My code so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('path') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f),index=[0])

df.plot.pie(subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

Is there a better way to plot those JSONs?

Files look like this, but have different number of `keys`

```
{"Restaurants": 678.7800000000001, "Utilities": 807.26, "Services": 35.67, "Transport": 1295.65, "Shopping": 1454.15, "Groceries": 1162.89}
```

I have found a partial solution based on the key:value format of all JSONs I use.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import json
with open('path') as f:
    dataDict = json.load(f)

x, y = zip(*dataDict.items())

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(y, labels=x)
ax1.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

If someone else has a better suggestion, I'm more than happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, index='orient')` to get dictionary format data into pandas. Kindly refer to [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```
data = {"Restaurants": 678.7800000000001, "Utilities": 807.26, "Services": 35.67, "Transport": 1295.65, "Shopping": 1454.15, "Groceries": 1162.89}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df
             0
Restaurants 678.78
Utilities   807.26
Services    35.67
Transport   1295.65
Shopping    1454.15
Groceries   1162.89

df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]